# Does PHP server-side processing count towards 'mobile data usage'

Tags: php

This might seem like a stupid question, but I am wondering whether PHP processing counts toward 'mobile data usage/data usage' or if it is only the send data, i.e. the output that does (the HTML). According to my logic is should not but I'm just curios to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mobile data usage count the traffic between your device and a server. Whatever the server has to do in order to reply to a request the device makes, be it just serving a static HTML page, running Node.js code, running PHP code or whatever else is inconsequential.